# Sort array of objects with representetive of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, object

I try to find most confident way for a simple question.
I have an array of rectangles with random height, i want to sort them for height using different sorting algorithm.

I find out two option:

- create another array of numbers that representate height
- just use height and sort rectangles dirrectly

And now i don`t know witch one is more efficient and confident for understanding, and where is moment where i should choose one or another.

Thanks a lot)

Comment: Please define what is a confident way. Also what kind of efficiency are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Arrays.sort with your custom Comparator sitting by rectangle’s height.